# how to obtain the explain result in mysql by code?

Tags: mysql

I planned to use rows in the explain result in replace of count(*). but I cannot get the rows number by code.

I have tried to treat the result as a table and select rows from it but it didn't work.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: cuz I don't really want the exact number of the total count. when using rows, I can get an approximate value of count(*) and this will save plenty of time when the table is large.  I have tried  it on a table of 30m rows. count(*)  took about 2.0s and explain only took 0.0s

Comment: I think explain uses information_schema.tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html - but the row count comes with a health warning - 'The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count.' ON the plus side information_schema.tables is a view.

Comment: thanks, man. the system table surely can be used to get the total rows of a table. here I have another question. rows in explain is an estimation of how many rows the query may scan. what if I want to get count() with certain conditions. for example, I want to use 'explain select * from user_info where id > 500' to replace
'select count(*) from user_info where id > 500'